# Convertir .pyw a .exe con cx_freeze (TKINTER)

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

He creado un reproductor MP3 con la libreria tkinter y quiero pasarlo a .exe

He probado con pyinstaller y no funcionaba

Cuento con la ultima version de python la 3.7.4

Aqui estan los modulos usados:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pygame
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import messagebox
import mutagen
import pygame
import getpass
```

Y aqui el setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}
base = None

setup(
    name = "Reproductor",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Un reproductor mp3 simple",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("reproductor.pyw", base = base)])
```

Una vez que abro  el .exe se abre la terminal y se repentinamente se cierra

Comment: AnimeZero, cuando crees el ejecutable, deja visible la consola, luego ve si aparece algún error y complementas tu pregunta.

Comment: No me sale ningun codigo de error en la terminal

Comment: Puedes intentar usar un archivo .py en lugar de .pyw para ver si ahi si sale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo entendido que para usar `tkinter` en Windows con `cx_freeze`, tienes que incluir explícitamente los .DLLs de la librería, así que pondrías esto en tu `setup.py` (reemplazando tu usuario de Windows):

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'
include_files = [r"C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]
```

Así mismo, debes incluir todos los paquetes que importas en el arg `packages`:

```
packages = ["tkinter", "pygame","os",[etc...]]
```

Luego en tu build_exe_options, incluyes los dlls que se especificaron y los paquetes:

```
build_exe_options = {
    "includes": ["tkinter"], 
    "include_files": include_files, 
    "packages": packages
}
```